# .htaccess - RewriteRule for 404 and query

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am very new to this stuff. I have a website with these `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` directives.

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So far everything works on my website but I have a small issue. I will try to explain it.

- `https://example.com/login` [Shows the login page]
- `https://example.com/asdasdasd` [Shows the 404 not found page]
- `https://example.com/login/asdasdasd` [Shows the login page too but it should show 404 not found page]
- `https://example.com/login%F0%9F%91%88%F0%9F%91%88%F0%9F%91%88` [Shows the login page too but it should show 404 not found page]

and I would like that every Query parameter will be removed.

If I open `https://example.com/login?fbclid=IwAR2w6Ff` that it redirects back to `https://example.com/login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem "the problem" is in your PHP code, not `.htaccess` as you seem to suggest.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

All requests are rewritten to `index.php` (your "front-controller") which then *routes* your URLs. It is this PHP script that determines whether `/login` or `/login/asdasdasd`, etc. resolve to a valid page on your site. This has nothing to do with Apache or your `.htaccess` file.

*Aside:* If there was a physical file at `/login.php` and MultiViews was enabled then this could be a different matter. However, it does not appear that MultiViews is enabled (ie. `Options All -Indexes`) so this does not seem to apply, even if `login.php` does exist as a physical file.

> and i would like that every Query parameter will be removed.
>
> if i open `https://example.com/login?fbclid=IwAR2w6Ff` that it redirects back to `https://example.com/login`

However, this you can do in `.htaccess`. At the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(login)$ /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

To remove the query string from *any* URL, not just `/login` then change the above `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects first to avoid caching issues.